# Is there a way to applie not order-independent variable in a parfor loop?

Tags: matlab, optimization, parfor

I'm trying to use parallel workers in an optimization problem but I cannot define V. I’m well aware that V is not order-independent, but such a variable (as V) has to be defined for any population-based optimization method. Are there any tips or tricks you can think of?

I even tried to save X after every iteration and load it before the V vector is calculated but then I have Transparency violation error.

```
clc; clear all; close all
T = 10;
Func = @sum;
Z = rand(1, 3);
X = rand(T, 3);
F=0.5;
parfor t=1:T
    R=randperm(T);
    R(find(R==t))=[];
    V=X(R(1),:)+F*(X(R(2),:)-X(R(3),:));
    TmpZ=Func(Z(1,:));TmpX=Func(X(t,:));
    if TmpZ < TmpX
        X(t,:)=Z(1,:); Y(t,1)=TmpZ;
    else
        X(t,:)=X(t,:); Y(t,1)=TmpX;
    end
end
```

Comment: This is impossible, **you're asking how to predict the future**. If you don't know `X(i)`, and `X(i+1), X(i+2), ...` depend on `X(i)` then how could you ever hope to compute them at the same time, or out of order? This is not a problem which can be sped up by throwing `parfor` at it. Instead, optimise your algorithm. You've not explained at all what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to suggest code improvements, but it looks like you should be able to vectorise some of the operations before you start looping through the linearly dependant stuff.

Comment: What is `X(t,:)=X(t,:);`? Looks like a bug... maybe you meant to use `TmpX`?

Comment: Not at all! What I think of is creating a matrix (X) to which every thread has access and can read or write. If X is used colletively than every thread has access to a temporary X which will influence the diversity of the search yet I can compensate that. The ith iteration only alters the ith row of the collective matrix but i is 1 for the first thread and 2 for the second, so they not supposed to crash. If V uses this (temporary) collective X it will do for an update. Like a storage box with labelled data. Is it possible in Matlab?

Comment: X(t,:)=X(t,:) symbolizes that I keep the original result, but you are right that part is unnecessary.

Comment: "The ith iteration only alters the ith row of the collective matrix but i is 1 for the first thread and 2 for the second, so they not supposed to crash." -- Sure, but every iteration reads all of `X`. You will get different results depending on the order of iterating, and hence you cannot use `parfor`. But I don't see where you use `V`? Why do you need to define it if you don't use it?

Comment: Another typo in the code, V=Z. This code above is a chunk of a simple differential evolution algorithm. If I could force this part to run in multiple threads, I could force a lot of other codes to run as well. 
The idea above is similar to a progress monitoring applied during parfor. Workers send their messages to the client and 'afterEach' the collective matrix is updated and V uses this updated collective matrix.

Comment: Wolfie is also right, I could improve the code by vectorizing some of the operations nevertheless, I cannot save time by improving the optimization algorithm when the real time-consuming part is the evaluation of the (ever changing) fitness function. parfor provides a possible solution, vectorization does not.

Comment: Your comments helped me to reconsider my thoughts towards multiple threads and I was able to reduce calculation time from 16.5 h to 57.4 min. Thanks!